# How to create custom Field with transition workflow in TFS

Tags: tfs, workflow, transition, custom-fields

How to create a custom field in TFS having transitions for each values

for e.g. I want to create a new custom field say Custom Status with values New,Approved,Assigned,Work Started and also want to assign custom transitions for this field

Is it possible to do so ?

2) Is it possible to assign some transitions to some other existing field for e.g. Priority

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

The only field that can have transmissions is the state field.

You can have the state transitions influence other fields, or values of one field trigger a change in another.